# Unable to delete a record with an alert message

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert

[image: Edit ancient-architecture-imy30]

I have react-table which is a simple CRUD application. I have a delete button for each row to delete that record.

On click of this delete button, an alert box pops up with options to delete and cancel

The delete option inside this alert box is unable to delete the record from the table. Although, I can see that deleted record in the browser console.  Well, then it's probably not able to update the table.

I think in `successDelete()`, I'm incorrectly passing the   `apiInfo: this.state.apiInfo.filter((ai, prop) => ai.uuid !== prop.uuid),`. But, now sure how to correct it.

Complete code can be found in the code sandbox. Below are relevant code snippets.

state variables:

```
this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      apiInfo: [],
      alert: null,
    };
```

the functions responsible for it:

```
  warningWithConfirmAndCancelMessage = () => {
    this.setState({
      alert: (
        <ReactBSAlert
          warning
          style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "-100px" }}
          title="Are you sure?"
          onConfirm={() => this.successDelete()}
          onCancel={() => this.cancelDetele()}
          confirmBtnBsStyle="success"
          cancelBtnBsStyle="danger"
          confirmBtnText="Yes, delete it!"
          cancelBtnText="Cancel"
          showCancel
          btnSize=""
        >
          You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!
        </ReactBSAlert>
      ),

    });
  };

  successDelete = () => {
    this.setState({
      alert: (
        <ReactBSAlert
          success
          style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "-100px" }}
          title="Deleted!"
          onConfirm={() => this.hideAlert()}
          onCancel={() => this.hideAlert()}
          confirmBtnBsStyle="success"
          btnSize=""
        >
          Your imaginary file has been deleted.
        </ReactBSAlert>
      ),
      apiInfo: this.state.apiInfo.filter((ai, prop) => ai.uuid !== prop.uuid),
    });
  };
  cancelDetele = () => {
    this.setState({
      alert: (
        <ReactBSAlert
          danger
          style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "-100px" }}
          title="Cancelled"
          onConfirm={() => this.hideAlert()}
          onCancel={() => this.hideAlert()}
          confirmBtnBsStyle="success"
          btnSize=""
        >
          Your imaginary file is safe :)
        </ReactBSAlert>
      ),
    });
  };
  hideAlert = () => {
    this.setState({
      alert: null,
    });
  };
```

and then in return() inside the render:

```
<div className="content">
          {this.state.alert}
<Button
              fill="true"
              onClick={this.warningWithConfirmAndCancelMessage}
              color="danger"
              size="sm"
              className="btn-icon btn-link remove"
              id="tooltip974171201"
            >
              <i className="fa fa-times" />
            </Button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to call `deleteAdminAPInfo` in your `successDelete` method.

Since the `deleteAdminAPIInfo` method is `async` it will return to you a promise. So you can chain a `then` to it to show the success popup like this:

```
successDelete = () => {
  this.deleteAdminAPInfo().then(() => {
    this.setState({
      alert: ( <
        ReactBSAlert success style = {
          {
            display: "block",
            marginTop: "-100px"
          }
        }
        title = "Deleted!"
        onConfirm = {
          () => this.hideAlert()
        }
        onCancel = {
          () => this.hideAlert()
        }
        confirmBtnBsStyle = "success"
        btnSize = "" >
        Your imaginary file has been deleted. <
        /ReactBSAlert>
      )
    });
  });
};
```

Also, since the `DELETE` call to the API seems to return the deleted data, you'll have to also filter it out from the state data on the frontend.

For that, you can do something like this in your `deleteAdminAPInfo` method:

```
deleteAdminAPInfo = async () => {
  console.log("get partner api info ----");
  await axios
    .delete("https://run.mocky.io/v3/de5b1f30-7150-42de-8c58-3729c7ee0b88")
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("get partner api info - api response:", response.data);
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        apiInfo: this.state.apiInfo.filter(
          (info) => response.data.findIndex(item => item.uuid === info.uuid) < 0
        )
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // handle error
      if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
        console.log("getmdi-Unable to fetch measurementsData", error.message);
      } else {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: true
        });
      }
    });
};
```

> Here's an **[Updated CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-brook-gnkmr?file=/src/ReactTable.js:2156-2192)** for your ref.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this solution does not work, if you `console.log(this.state.appInfo)` you can see its still there

Comment: I think you forgot to add `this.state.appInfo.filter`

Comment: @SiddAjmera after clicking on YES, DELETE IT in the modal, the page shows loading... instead of the updated view with updated table.

Comment: I'm already doing that filtering and the deleteAdminAPI will be used eventually but for now since, I am using mock api.. I gotta make it work for the front end. Since, I obviously cannot send the data back to a mock api server.

Comment: as of now, there is only 1 pair of data `UUID`. But in reality, there would be many more and `[0]` will check only at zeroth index. Whereas the data could be in any row. that's why I am sure `response.data[0].uuid`

Comment: and I just implemented your solution in code, I think it's  `apiInfo: this.state.apiInfo.filter(
          (info) => info.uuid !== response.data[0].uuid
        )` in the `deleteAdminAPInfo()`. It seems right though, but still not working as it shoudl.

Comment: I was assuming that the API is going to return just the deleted data. And based on the table, I didn't see any checkboxes or delete selected button, so I took the liberty to assume that only one item can be deleted at a time. 

Comment: right. understood. there could be n number of rows in this table and the user can delete any row he would want. sorry, I should have clarified this earlier. now, can you please update your `codeSandbox` :)

Comment: onClick of `Yes, delete it!` the page goes either goes blank or displays `Loading...`